# How to use .unionAll() in a reduce expression to create single dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to learn to use functional programming constructs like `reduce`, and I'm trying to grok how to use it to `union` multiple `dataframes` together.  I was able to accomplish it with a simple for loop.  You can see the commented out `expr` which was my attempt, the problem I'm running into is the fact that `reduce` is a `Python` function, and so I'm interleaving `Python` and `Spark` code in the same function, which doesn't make the compiler happy.

Here is my code:

```py
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
        [
            ('1', '2', '3'),
        ],
        ['a', 'b', 'c']
    )

df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('4', '5', '6'),
    ],
    ['a', 'b', 'c']
)

df3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('7', '8', '9'),
    ],
    ['a', 'b', 'c']
)

l = [df2, df3]

# expr = reduce(lambda acc, b: acc.unionAll(b), l, '')
for df in l:
    df1 = df1.unionAll(df)

df1.select('*').show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide incorrect initial value for `reduce` what leads to a situations where you call

```
''.unionAll(b)
```

and it should be obvious it doesn't make sense. Either drop `initial`:

```
reduce(lambda acc, b: acc.unionAll(b), l) if l else None
```

or replace `''` with a `DataFrame` with a valid schema:

```
first, *rest = l
reduce(lambda acc, b: acc.unionAll(b), rest, first)
```

Also there is no need for lambda expression:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, rest, first)
```

If you're in adventures mood you can even monkey patch `DataFrame`:

```
DataFrame.__add__ = DataFrame.unionAll
sum(rest, first)
```

On a side note iterative unions without truncating lineage are not the best idea in Spark.